# Python Error checking using pymysql get errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, pymysql, thonny

I have put together an example python scripts for myself to understand how to connect to a MySQL database using `pymysql`. It works but in Thonny-Assistant it is showing a few errors and I am asking for help to understand these errors to see if they are important.

The example script creates a table in the database, adds random data, updates the data, and then deletes the data and then the table.

My first error is line 43 where I am attempting some error checking. This is line 43:

```
print("pre_load_data: Connection error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
```

which gives the error

```
Argument 'builtins.str' does not match format type 'd'
```

Then another error is line 61 which produces 2 errors. This is line 61:

```
with connection:
```

```
'Connection' has no attribute '__enter__'

'Connection' has no attribute '__exit__'
```

Then on line 106, I get many different types of errors which are just assigning a variable with a field from the database.

```
first_name_variable = result['FIRST_NAME']
```

```
No overload variant of '__getitem__ of 'tuple' matches argument type 'str'
Possible overload variants

def __getitem__(self, int) -> Any

def __getitem__(self, slice) -> Tuple[Any,...]

Value of type 'Union[Tuple[Any,...],Dict[str, Ant], None]' is not indexable
```

Thank you for reading any any help would be grateful to understand.

Here is my full script...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Python Database Master File with Error Checking
import pymysql
# Just used for timing and random stuff
import sys
import time
import random
import string

def get_random_string(length):
    # choose from all lowercase letter
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    print("Random string of length", length, "is:", result_str)
    return result_str

start = time.time()
print("starting @ ",start)
runallcode = 0 # Change to 1 to delete records, trucate and drop
sqlinsert = []
FirstName = get_random_string(4)
for y in range (1,3):
    presqlinsert = (
        FirstName,
        get_random_string(10),
        y,
        "M",
        random.randint(0,50)
        )
    sqlinsert.append(presqlinsert)
print("sqlinsert @ ",sqlinsert)

# Open database connection
try:
    # Connect to the database
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='192.168.0.2',
        user='weby',
        password='password',
        database='datadb',
        charset='utf8mb4',
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
except pymysql.Error as e:
    print("pre_load_data: Connection error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
    sys.exit(1)

# Simple SQL just to get Version Number
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = connection.cursor()
# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
data = cursor.fetchone()
print ("Database version : %s " % data)

# Check if EMPLOYEE table exists, if so drop it
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = connection.cursor()
# Drop table if it already exist using execute() method.
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMPLOYEE")

with connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        try:
            # Create a new table called EMPLOYEE
            sql = "CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,FIRST_NAME CHAR(20) NOT NULL,LAST_NAME CHAR(20),AGE INT,SEX CHAR(1),INCOME FLOAT,PRIMARY KEY (id))"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save your changes.
            connection.commit()
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("# Create a new table: error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        finally:
            print("# Create a new table: clean up operations")

        try:
            # ALTER TABLE to add index
            sql = "ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD INDEX (id);"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save your changes.
            connection.commit()
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("# ALTER TABLE to add index: error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        finally:
            print("# ALTER TABLE to add index: clean up operations")
    
        try:
            # Create a new record direct values
            sql = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE, SEX, INCOME)  VALUES ('Thirsty','Lasty',69,'M',999)"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save your changes.
            connection.commit()
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("# Create a new record direct values: error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        finally:
            print("# Create a new record direct values: clean up operations")

        try:
            # SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchone()
            sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE id = 1"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            print(result)
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("# SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchone(): error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        finally:
            print("# SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchone(): clean up operations")
            first_name_variable = result['FIRST_NAME']
            print("Extract data from result into variable: ", first_name_variable)

        try:
            # Create a new record using variables
            sql = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE, SEX, INCOME)  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, ('Qweyac', 'PterMohan', 40, 'M', 5450))
            # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save your changes.
            connection.commit()
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("# Create a new record using variables: error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        finally:
            print("# Create a new record using variables: clean up operations")

        try:
            # SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchall()
            sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            print(result)
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("# SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchall(): error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        finally:
            print("# SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchall(): clean up operations")

        try:
            # Create a new record using array and cursor.executemany
            sql = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE, SEX, INCOME)  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            cursor.executemany(sql,sqlinsert)
            # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save your changes.
            connection.commit()
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("# Create a new record using array and cursor.executemany: error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        finally:
            print("# Create a new record using array and cursor.executemany: clean up operations")  
            sqlinsert.clear()

        try:
            # SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchall()
            sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            print(result)
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("# SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchall(): error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        finally:
            print("# SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchall(): clean up operations")


        try:
            # UPDATE record using variables
            sql = "UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET FIRST_NAME = %s, LAST_NAME = %s WHERE id = 2"
            cursor.execute(sql, ('Peter', 'Brown'))
            # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save your changes.
            connection.commit()
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("# UPDATE record using variables: error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        finally:
            print("# UPDATE record using variables: clean up operations")  


        try:
            # SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchone()
            sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE id = 2"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            print(result)
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("# SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchone(): error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        finally:
            print("# SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchone(): clean up operations")

        try:
            # SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchall()
            sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            print(result)
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("# SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchall(): error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        finally:
            print("# SELECT record direct values using cursor.fetchall(): clean up operations")
            print("Total number of rows in table: ", cursor.rowcount)
            print("\nPrinting each row")
            for row in result:
                for key,value in row.items():
                    print('The key is %s'%key,'The value is %s'%value)

        if runallcode == 1:
            try:
                # DELETE FROM table called
                sql = "DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE id = %s"
                deletesql = 1
                cursor.execute(sql,deletesql)
                # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save your changes.
                connection.commit()
            except pymysql.Error as e:
                print("# Delete From table: error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
            finally:
                print("# Delete  From table: clean up operations")
                
            try:
                # Trucate table called EMPLOYEE
                sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE EMPLOYEE"
                cursor.execute(sql)
                # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save your changes.
                connection.commit()
            except pymysql.Error as e:
                print("# Truncate table: error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
            finally:
                print("# Truncate table: clean up operations")

            try:
                # DROP table called EMPLOYEE
                sql = "DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE"
                cursor.execute(sql)
                # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save your changes.
                connection.commit()
            except pymysql.Error as e:
                print("# DROP table: error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
            finally:
                print("# DROP table: clean up operations")

end = time.time()
print("ending @ ",end - start)
```

Can anyone explain the errors and how can I solve them?

Comment: Your `print()` line is correct according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56291330/1491895). So I think there's a problem with the type annotation for `pymysql.Error.args`.

Comment: Just use `%s` instead of `%d` – or better yet, f-strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last error, you can add a type annotation indicating that the cursor only returns dictionaries. Use:

```
cursor: pymysql.cursors.DictCursor = connection.cursor()
```

I don't think Thonny is able to infer this automatically from `cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor`

Regarding the error on the `with` statement, it looks like context manager support was removed from pymysql connections. See [Can I use pymysql.connect() with "with" statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214658/can-i-use-pymysql-connect-with-with-statement). So just get rid of that `with` statement, and put `connection.close()` at the end (or just exit the script, it will close automatically).